# java output single line instead of line by line

Tags: java

I have a sample java program as follows:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i =0;i<100;i++){  
        System.out.println("Value:"+i);
        }
    }

}
```

I run this program in CMD using the following command: java Test

I am getting output as follows:

```
Value:1
Value:2
..........
```

What I want is the output should be on a single line like:

Value 1

Instead of displaying each value on a separate line, it should change the printed value on the same line as it counts. How do I do that?

Comment: You might check out [jline](http://jline.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html), and in particular `ConsoleReader.killLine`.

Comment: You can't really do what you're asking in a console-based application, without relying on OS-specific command's such as `cls` in Windows.  Perhaps you could write this as a Swing GUI, with a JLabel whose text keeps updating.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
String clrCommand = System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")? "cls" : "clear";
for(int i =0;i<100;i++){  
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(clrCommand);
    System.out.print("Value:"+i);
}
```

In this case: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls")` (or "clear") clears your console, and then, `System.out.print("Value:"+i)` prints the value. so you will have the effect of only one line, with the number changing.

This does not work on all systems. if it does not work, then the best solution is to spam the `\n` symbol, which can be quite heavy in terms of performance

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){  
    for (int n=0;n<100;n++) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print("Value:"+i);
}
```

Comment: @Victor2748 I think he wants it like "Value: 1" which will change to "Value: 2" on the next run, but stay on the same line. So it'd be an overwriting thing.

Comment: i guess that is what you want, right? Please correct me if I'm not answering your question

Comment: You may want to add an if-statement to check if the current OS is Windows or not. Windows uses "cls" instead of "clear"

Comment: This isn't reliable at all. Much better to use backspaces than to try to shell out, which will fail with the wrong OS, an unusual terminal setup...

Comment: @Victor2748 now it is not Even prointing anyting

Comment: Well, you're probably not going to see anything unless you add some delay inside the loop...

Comment: @ChrisMartin yes, I know

Comment: @Victor2748 its not working and nothing is get print on CMD now

Answer (score -1):

Use StringBuilder for it.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Value -> ");
        for(int i =0;i<100;i++){  
            builder.append(i);
            builder.append(" -- "); // this line is for distinction from other value
        }
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: number should come onlyonce it should change like counter!!

Answer (score -3):

The "println" will print a line after the string, which "print" never does.

public class Test {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i =0;i<100;i++){  
           if(i=0){
               System.out.print("Value: "+i);
           }else{
               System.out.print(" "+i);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide an explanation of how this code solves the problem that the OP has. This will add value to your answer and prevent it from being deleted.

Comment: @JamesMassey [Reviewing Low Quality Posts - Answers without explanation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260411/reviewing-low-quality-posts-answers-without-explanation)

Comment: @JamesMassey  Ok,I am new here and don't know the rules very well. I will add explanation with the answer next time.